# SilverStripe LeftModelAdmin List View is not showing all the columns

Tags: silverstripe

I am developing a SilverStripe project. I am new to SilverStripe. Now, I am using LeftModelAdmin to display the list of data which has a menu item in the admin panel. But my list view is not showing all the columns. Instead, it is displaying only one column. This is what I have done so far.

This is my model class

```
namespace {

    use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

    class ContactFormSubmission extends DataObject
    {
        private static $db = [
            'Name' => 'Varchar',
            'Email' => 'Varchar',
            'Message' => 'Text',
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my ModelAdmin class for the model

```
namespace {

    use SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin;

    class ContactFormSubmissionAdmin extends ModelAdmin
    {
        private static $menu_title = 'Enquiries';

        private static $url_segment = 'enquiries';

        private static $managed_models = [
            ContactFormSubmission::class,
        ];

        private static $summary_fields = [
            'Name' => 'Name',
            'Email' => 'Email',
            'Message' => 'Message',
        ];
    }
}
```

When I view the list view in the admin panel, I only see one column in the admin panel as in the screenshot below.

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`summary_fields` configuration belongs on the model, not the model admin.

Try moving:

```
private static $summary_fields = [
    'Name' => 'Name',
    'Email' => 'Email',
    'Message' => 'Message',
];
```

to your model (`ContactFormSubmission`).